# Jenkins Pipeline - Pass Artifact URL between stages

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

My usecase is to build a Java job , deploy a tar.gz.zip to nexus and pass on this artifact URL to further stages.

I am using the below command in a script that does other validation:

```
mvn -B clean deploy -U package deploy:deploy -DskipNexusStagingDeployMojo=true -DaltDeploymentRepository=dev-snapshots::default::https://<myrepo.com>
```

Below would be my stages:

```
stage('publish'){    
  //push to Nexus  
 }
stage('processing'){    
 // get the artifact url from above step
}
```

I don't want to use "archiveartifacts" as I am already storing the artifacts, I do not want to archive it. I just need the URL.

So far , all I could manage was to get the entire output of the deploy to a text file.

```
sh "deploy.sh > deploy.txt"
```

However ,new File(deploy.txt) does not work with Pipelines as groovy gets executed on master and file is created on slaves. And readfile('deploy.txt') does not take any regex. So I am not able to parse the file to get the artifact url.

Is there any better way to get the artifact url from publish to processing stage in pipeline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about storing value in a variable during `publish` stage and reading this variable during `processing` stage? Consider following Jenkins pipeline example:

```
def artifactUrl = ''

pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Build') { 
            steps {
                script {
                   artifactUrl = 'test'
                }
            }
        }

        stage('Publish') {
            steps {
                echo "Current artifactUrl is '${artifactUrl}'"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I run it I get following output:

```
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in /var/jenkins_home/workspace/test-pipeline
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Build)
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Publish)
[Pipeline] echo
Current artifactUrl is 'test'
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Of course there is an open question how you get your artifact URL, but if you only can get it from your publish command then passing it between stages shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: The challenge is I get the artifact url from mvn deploy in console. Are you suggesting to access the console of ongoing job to get the url ?

Comment: @user5290853 I don't know what is the best way to get artifact URL. If parsing output in text file worked for you then you can try something similar with parsing output inside the script. If you run `sh(script: "mvn ...", returnStdout: true)` you will get the output returned from the sh command. If it's easy for you to parse it then it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Based on @Szymon Stepniak comment  implemented it the below way:

```
 def out = sh(script: "/myscript.sh" , returnStdout: true )
 Pattern p = Pattern.compile("INFO] Uploaded: .*bin.tar.gz")
 Matcher m = p.matcher(out);
```